# How can I use a #define statement to perform byte swapping on a type `float` variable in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c-preprocessor

I am tinkering with a snippet of code I got from a library of byte-swapping routines [1](http://repo-genesis3.cbi.utsa.edu/crossref/ns-sli/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h.html) and learning about bitwise manipulation, usage of `#define`, pointers and type casting :

```
#define __bswap_constant_32(x) \
  ((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |               \
  (((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | (((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))
```

Using the snippet in a function as follows worked as expected:

```
void swapbytes32(void *pt)
{
    *((unsigned int *)pt) = (((  *((unsigned int *)pt) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((  *((unsigned int *)pt) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |   \
     ((  *((unsigned int *)pt) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | ((  *((unsigned int *)pt) & 0x000000ff) << 24));
}
```

For instance a call such as

```
float x = 1.0;
swapbytes32((void*)(&x));
```

gives x = 0x0        0       80       3f
and swapped x = 0x3f       80        0        0

But notice all the awkward type conversions. The proper usage of type casting confuses me. In the above function I used it to suppress errors such as:

> In function 'swapbytes32': hex_testi_3.c:200:31: warning:
>   dereferencing 'void *' pointer [enabled by default]   *((unsigned int
>   *)pt) = (((  *pt) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((  *pt) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |   \

Here is what I think I understand so far:

- dereferencing a void pointer is not possible because you have no idea about the byte length of the implied type or information on how to use the data in an operation.
- the type casting above tells the compiler to treat the data type in the address  as an `unsigned int` but does not change the bitwise structure of the stored data.

What I am not completely sure about is why in some instances the compiler balks depending on where I perform type casting, or doesn't perform the cast as expected.

How can I use the above `#define` statement (or a similar one) to perform byte swapping on a type `float` variable?

Comment: I don't see how the macro version is supposed to work; doing `&` between a `float` and an `int` does not access the float's representation! `x` would have to be `*(unsigned int *)y` which reintroduces the aliasing problems.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No the macro doesn't work at all if you try to pass it a `float`, that is the problem. See my answer for what seems a workaround with extensive type casting, just like in the function above.

Comment: More specifically you can't use `bswap_constant_32(&x)`, rather you have to use something like `bswap_constant_32((unsigned int*)(&x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to convert between a float and its bit-representation as int, is to use a union instead of casting a pointer. If you can guarantee that the size of the int is the same as the size of the float, one should hold the whole bit pattern of the other, without *any* intermediate type conversion. Between `stdint.h`, and the standardisation on IEEE754 single for `float` (nearly ubiquitous, but you can test for it with `#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__`), this should be safe on most systems.

You can write a simple wrapper macro that converts a float to an int before passing it to the swap implementation given above:

```
#define BSWAP_FLOAT(F) \
  __bswap_constant_32((union { uint32_t i; float f; }){ .f = (F) }.i)
```

This creates an anonymous union in-place, initializes its `f` field with the float value, and reads back its bit pattern through the `i` field (which is then passed to the swap macro).

To convert the returned value of the macro *back* to another float, wrap it in another union literal expression that goes the opposite way, initializing with the int and extracting the float (shown as a second wrapper for simplicity):

```
#define BSWAP_FLOAT2(F) \
  ((union { uint32_t i; float f; }){ .i = BSWAP_FLOAT(F) }.f)
```

In-place union literals are very useful for this sort of thing.

See it in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define __bswap_constant_32(x) \
  ((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |               \
  (((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | (((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))

#define BSWAP_FLOAT(F) \
  __bswap_constant_32((union { uint32_t i; float f; }){ .f = (F) }.i)

#define FLOAT_BITS(F) ((union { uint32_t i; float f; }){ .f = (F) }.i)

int main(void) {
    float f = 4.0f;
    printf("%x %x\n", FLOAT_BITS(f), BSWAP_FLOAT(f));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code **invokes undefined behavior** since it **breaks the strict aliasing rule badly** by accessing an object through an incompatible type (`float` vs. `unsigned int`). There's an exception from this rule that you can exploit: it is allowed to inspect an object's representation using a pointer to character type.

Also, you don't really need to spell out the cast every single time; why not just declare a pointer **once?** Like this:

```
void swap_byte_order(void *ptr, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *p = ptr, *q = p + n - 1;
    for (; p < q; p++, q--) {
        unsigned char tmp = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = tmp;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
float f = 3.14;
swap_byte_order(&f, sizeof f);
```

Much cleaner, strictly conforming, better overall.

Comment: By strict aliasing I suppose you mean that data should be passed between variables with the same (or nested i.e. int to long int) data types?

Comment: The multiple pointer type casts in my function don't look pretty I admit, I also have written (another) function much like yours (with char pointers). However I wanted to see if I could not implement a bitwise manipulation routine. In particular the library I reference seems to suggest that the use of a define with bit manipulation is much faster (if less general) than a function call.

Comment: @TryHard Depending on the particular piece of hardware, either bitwise operations or memory access may be faster. So, the assertion that "bit manipulation is faster" is simply not true as-is. Also, my function is tiny -- it will be inlined by any decently-optimizing compiler so there'll be no call overhead.

Answer (score 1):

As I drafted this question I realized that I was closer to the answer than I realized. Here's what I've got so far:

Try using a pointer in the define statement.

For instance if I define the following

```
#define bswap_constant_32_(px) \
                    *(px)=  ( ((  *(px) & 0xff000000) >> 24) \
                            | ((  *(px) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) \
                            | ((  *(px) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) \
                            | ((  *(px) & 0x000000ff) << 24));
```

if

```
unsigned int n = 123456;
```

either of the following works:

```
n = bswap_constant_32(&n);
bswap_constant_32(&n);

// n before: 0x40       e2        1        0
//    after: 0x 0        1       e2       40
```

because the data types (and so bit structure) match.

However, this works:

```
 float x = 1.0;
 bswap_constant_32((unsigned int*)(&x));
```

but this doesn't:

```
 x=bswap_constant_32((unsigned int*)(&x));
```

result:  0x0       3f        0       47

The compiler seems to perform a data type conversion and rearranges the underlying bits before passing the data to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You were both very correct that you were close, and that pointers provided the answer. You can use a simple cast to operate on the `float` value at a particular address, and make the results assignable to an `unsigned integer`. You can eliminate `swapped` entirely below and produce the same output with `printf ("  __bswap_constant_32  : %02x\n\n", __bswap_constant_32(*ai));`. Take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __bswap_constant_32(x) \
((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | (((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |               \
(((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | (((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))

int main (void) {

    float f = 123.45;
    unsigned int *ai = (unsigned int *)&f;
    unsigned int swapped;

    printf ("\nSwapping bytes of float: '%.2f'\n\n", f);
    printf (" %.2f as unsigned int: %02x\n\n", f, *ai);

    swapped = __bswap_constant_32(*ai);

    printf ("  __bswap_constant_32  : %02x\n\n", swapped);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/bswc

Swapping bytes of float: '123.45'

 123.45 as unsigned int: 42f6e666

  __bswap_constant_32  : 66e6f642
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well going from float to the unsigned int swapped. However I have some surprising results when I try to recast the pointer of swapped as float, for instance `float *pf;
 pf = (float*)&swapped;
 printf ("  and converted back to float  :  (%02x) %0.2e\n\n", *pf, *pf);`

Comment: In fact I was really surprised by the output of appending the following to your code: `float \*pf  = (float\*)&swapped;
 printf ("  and converted back to float  :   %0.2g (%02x)\n\n", swapped, swapped);´

Comment: Evidently the mere act of using printf is enough to cast the variable and mess around with the underlying bits (as a relative novice this is a real surprise!)

Comment: When you assign to `swapped` it is the `byte swapped` value stored as an `unsigned int` **not** the original floating point encoded in `IEEE-754` FP format.

Comment: Yep, I mixed up use of pointers and assignments in a couple of previous comments - it all works out in your answer, thanks!